# Disable the push-screen popup on iphone in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, popup

I am making a cordova based iphone application running phonegap and jQuery mobile.

i want to remove the event that happends on iphone when you push down a link on the screen you get like a "pop-up" that's says if you want to open or copy the link.

Is it a CSS or phonegap based sollution i need to find?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-touch-callout Try this -webkit-touch-callout